# What is alternative for Appdelegate of iOS in Android

Tags: android, ios, appdelegate, devicetoken

I am newbie to android.

I want to initialize certain parameters like **api key and device token** (as are in iOS).

**Device token** which is unique id of iphone,which is used to send notification to that device.

**Api key** is unique key which identifies our application.(Every third party has its own API key like Facebook,Twitter,Google Plus,etc.)

AND

methods like **didRegisterForRemoteNotification and didReceiveRemoteNotification** (as are in iOS) in android.

So i want to know alternative for this in android.

In iOS,We store **deviceToken to send notification** ,But in android what we store to send notification ?

Comment: You may want to explain more what are they in iOS

Comment: Agreed. Citing another OS as an an *example* of behavior is fine, but you need to explain *the behavior* clearly for those unfamiliar with the other OS. For example: what "api key"? What "device token"?

Comment: @CommonsWare;@Alex : Ok,I edited my question.

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I have several listed at http://www.andglobe.com. You may have better luck using a site that is a language that is more comfortable for you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [in this guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), you should keep note of the project id (referred to as SENDER_ID in code)

```
/**
 * Substitute you own sender ID here.
 */
 String SENDER_ID = "Your-Sender-ID";
```

You'll be using it later for registering the device:

```
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```